# Организовать простой веб-сервис

Tags: веб-сервер, vps, linux

Есть голая VPS-ка на линуксе. Задача - организовать простенькую страничку, с помощью которой можно будет аплоадить большие (300 мегабайт) файлы на сервер. Тупо html-ка с парой формочек, доступная из веба.

Поднимать апач + php для такой ерунды не хочется, тем более, грамотно конфигурировать я их не умею. Может есть более простые варианты? С помощью чего такое наиболее легко и быстро реализовать?

Comment: поднимайте nginx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Цитата Тупо html-ка с парой формочек,доступная из веба.
>
> Поднимать апач + php для такой ерундыне хочется,
>
> Цитата

а ктож тогда будет обслуживать те самые html-ки? к тому же 300 Мб - объем, который превышает "дефолтные" лимиты. Так что веб-сервер прийдется и ставить и настраивать...

======================================================с "собственным веб-сервером" есть еще такая штука как webmin, или же usermin. Если задача чисто загружать и скачивать файлы, то возможно, usermin подойдет. У него есть подобные функции в меню, НО есть одно "но" войти в него смогут лишь пользователи, созданные в системе (в самом линуксе). Хотя, может быть этот факт защиты информации наоборот, будет совсем не лишним?..

http://www.webmin.com/usermin.html

Answer (score 1):

Nginx upload module вам должен подойти.

Answer (score 0):

То же Mojolicious-приложение может работать как веб-сервис. Из требования более-менее свежая версия Perl.

Comment: В Mojolicious естьо один небольшой недостаток: его вместе с готовым сайтом невозможно таскать с собой на флешке, как это возможно в Денвере!

Comment: винду то таскать на флешке? :)

Answer (score -1):

Ну блин, так сервак же на голом железе всё одно подымать! Вот тут есть, хоть и с Апачем, но "искаропки": http://www.denwer.ru/ Он, хоть и для тестинга в основном, но при надлежащей прикрутке и в боевом режиме неплохо работает. Там всё написано!

А дальше - вот: http://www.joomla-docs.ru/%D3%F1%F2%E0%ED%EE%E2%EA%E0_Joomla_%ED%E0_%C4%E5%ED%E2%E5%F0

А потом - сюда: http://www.joomla-docs.ru/FAQ_по_шаблонам_Joomla

Comment: Во первых - VPS-ка на линуксе. Денвер виндовс-онли. Во вторых - в вопросе четко указана задача - организовать простой аплоадинг файлов на сервер. А вы мне зачем-то FAQ джумлы кидаете. Джумлы!

Comment: Прошу прощения, был невнимателен!

Comment: @Anton\ Reshin, кроме всего прочего, Joomla *в принципе* не лучший выбор. **ИМХО**